# Unable to preset select with 'selected' value - Angular bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4, pipe

https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-ujb1nw

I'm struggling to get the documented 'selected' tag to pre-select my default select value. I think this might have something to do with the unique pipe I am applying and the way angular works.

I have tried various ways to get this as default/on load. e.g.

```
<option value="All" selected>All</option>
<option *ngFor="let entry of timeLine | filterUnique" value="{{entry.location}}">{{entry.location}}</option>
```

Also tried `[selected]='selected'`, `ngvalue='null'`, `ngvalue='All'`

Maybe I have to add something to my uniquefilter.pipe?

I have created a pipe to pick up values for select options, some of these values are duplicated so I have added a unique pipe to only get the value once to populate my dropdown/select options. - maybe this is the cause that its not reading 'selected'?

Any help or experience here would be appreciated. thanks

https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-ujb1nw

Comment: So you want to select the option 'All' by default right?

Comment: If I understand right you want to preselect some options. you just need to add this in your timeline.component.ts: filteredLocation = 'north';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in your timeline component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredLocation = 'All';
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there. You just forgot to declare the `filteredLocation` in your component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-timeline',
  templateUrl: './timeline.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./timeline.component.css']
})
export class TimelineComponent {
  timeLine = [...];
  filteredLocation = 'All'; // Preset with the default value
}
```

You don't need the `selected` property on the "All" option then.

Comment: Yes. Becasue selected does not work together with ngModel. You need to preset the model when you work with ngModel

Answer (score 2):

As per the code you have posted in stackblitz you just need to take a variable named "filteredLocation" in timeline.component.ts file and set default value to that variable.

Sample Code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/timeline-angular-7-puycmz